# First Name and Last Name Validation vs XSS Attack

Tags: validation, xss

My online research seems to show that firstnames and lastnames should not be heavily validated, to accommodate the variety of names out there. In fact, people have even advocated no validation altogether for the names. However, the possibility of xss attacks via the input fields make me worried. I checked the google naming guidelines, and they seem pretty relaxed and allow unicode characters as well as stuff like "%$#^&*...." !!

So, what would be the best approach to take, and how do I balance this out ?

ps - I don't intend to spark a debate here. I am genuinely confused and need help understanding the best approach to take !

Comment: Validation is a different concept from XSS. You validate content to make sure that the content does make sense. A telephone number only makes sense if it is a sequence of numbers with a certain length for example. XSS is something where a website does not properly escape user input before displaying it to the user again, resulting in third-party resources to load and or run.

Comment: With all due respect, I never claimed that validation and xss were the same thing. However, they are correlated. Weak validation of user input is likely to increase the chances of xss attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Validation and XSS are two very different concepts. You cannot balance them. You cannot "sometimes allow XSS". You also do not want to allow input that does not make sense, or that you can't use. If you require an email for something, you can allow an user to enter "mailme at gmail dot com", but if you do not know how to parse this, then there is no point in allowing this as an input in the first place.

When you talk about validating a 'first name field', you ask yourself: "What kind of data do I want to accept in this field, and what kind of data do I not want to accept in this field?". I am not aware of a language where "%" can be part of a first name, so it is probably a safe bet to disallow this character. You have to tackle this problem alone, without even thinking about XSS. If a character, or a sequence of characters, does not make sense as a value for the thing you want to know, you should not include it. If a character does make sense to include, you should not decide otherwise because it has some special meaning.

XSS is the problem where incorrectly escaped (user) input is returned to the browser, allowing a possible attacker to load/run third-party scripts. It has nothing to do with validation. If the character "a" is potentially unsafe, would you disallow it from the first name field? The solution can be found in the definition: The problem exists if, and only if, the user input is incorrectly escaped.

Think about how you are going to sent back this data to the user. I take as example an input field: `<input value="" />`, but if you were going to put it in a textarea for example, you would need to alter your data for that. Inserting it between a `<div></div>` tag would require something entirely different again, and inserting it inside a script that is in `<script></script>` tags would require something different than all the previous things. There is no one-size-fits-all-solution.

For the input field example, find out what characters have a special meaning in this input field. The delimiter of the value attribute (`"` in `value=""`) is one of the characters that has a special meaning. If there are any other special characters, you find them in accompanying documentation. You have to escape such characters. Escaping is the act of removing the special meaning from a character. How you do that can be found in the accompanying documentation. In case of an input element in html, you'll need to turn the special character into it's entity-form (`"` would become `&quot;`). Php provides built-in functions to do this, but you should always be wary of **what such a function actually does** and **if this function actually gives the desired output for every use-case**.

tl;dr There is no balance. You use validation on a field to get the data you actually want. If you want to present this data to the user, you have to escape the data for the special case where you want to display this data.

---

Example: Let's look at the following case. We have a textarea. We allow the characters a-z, <, >, (, ), {, }, / and ; in any order. If the textarea contains other characters we consider it *invalid*. If the textarea is *valid*, we put the characters in the textarea between `<div>` and `</div>` in the html document.

From the definition above, you can derive that `asdf` is a valid input and that `<script>alert();</script>` is also a valid input, but `123` isn't. That is the definition. The logic that handles validation should flawlessly discriminate between those two things. You probably notice that the second valid input may provide a problem, but that is of no concern to the validate function. The validate function only checks if the text matches the description of what we consider valid input.

If the text in the textarea is valid, the definition says we should put it between the div tags. This is where you start worrying about XSS. There are some characters, namely the `<` and `>` character that have a special meaning in html. Because they are valid input, we should remove their special meaning when we insert them in the html. If the textarea is invalid, we can't do anything. We would display a descriptive error message how it should be improved.

The pseudo-implementation below shows what I try to explain above. In a real-life application that communicates with the server, the server should do validation too, but it should show how both concepts are separated and should allow you to test things.

```js
$('#billy').on('click', function(e) {
  if (validate($('#txt').val())) {
    $('#status').text("The textarea is valid. The contents have been inserted as html in the page.");
    $('#result').html($('#txt').val());
  } else {
    $('#status').text("The textarea is INVALID. It contains characters we don't want.");
  }
});

$('#betty').on('click', function(e) {
  if (validate($('#txt').val())) {
    $('#status').text("The textarea is valid. The contents have been inserted as html in the page.");
    $('#result').html(escapeforhtml($('#txt').val()));
  } else {
    $('#status').text("The textarea is INVALID. It contains characters we don't want.");
  }
});

function validate(txt) {
  return txt.match(/^[a-z{}\/\(\)<>;]*$/);
}

//We know only a limited amount of characters can be inserted.
//From those, < and > are the only characters that have a special
//meaning.
function escapeforhtml(txt) {
  return txt.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="status"></div>

<textarea id="txt" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="billy" value="Do something">
<input type="button" id="betty" value="Do something while ESCAPING">

<p>Result:</p>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to elaborate your answer. Unfortunately, for me the penny hasn't dropped yet. At the moment, I can't fully grasp how you have completely separated validation from xss. Perhaps, I need to do more research before I can appreciate your answer... but as of yet, I simply can't believe that, "It has nothing to do with validation." 

Would you be kind enough to indicate any articles online that you think will help me appreciate your answer more ?

Thanks in anycase.

Comment: I have added an example and a snippet to the answer that should hopefully clarify some of what I say.

Comment: If you can edit my answer to edit out ` (random nonsense to bypass faulty proxy)` I would be grateful. It appears I am behind a faulty proxy that drops the connection once it detects that phrase, not allowing me to save my edit. Brilliant, really...